# Hide result block in SharePoint 2013 search

Tags: 2013, search, search-results

I have configured a result block to show people results that always is showing in all the pages: Everything, News, Library, Document centers, People and Videos.

I want to **hide** this result block in the people and the videos page.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the Result Source to "Local SharePoint Results". (You probably selected "All Sources".)